# DatagramChannel  packet listener taking high CPU

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, datagram

I have a packet Listener Thread in Java for UDP packets along with 2-3 other threads.

It was running fine till today but now the process javaw.exe has started using CONSTANT 50% CPU.

Here is my code.

```
public class PacketListenerThread implements Runnable {
    private SocketAddress receivedSocketAddress;
    private DatagramChannel channel;
    private ExecutorService pool;

    public PacketListenerThread(DatagramChannel channel, ExecutorService pool) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            receivedSocketAddress = null;
            ByteBuffer recvbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1400);
            recvbuf.clear();
            try {
                receivedSocketAddress = channel.receive(recvbuf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (receivedSocketAddress != null) {
                pool.submit(new PacketHandlerRunnable(new TaskObject(receivedSocketAddress, recvbuf)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have stopped all other threads but this thread still uses "CONSTANT" 50% CPU .

Comment: And I assume it is not throwing tons of exceptions over and over?  I suspect that there are some exceptions that should cause the thread to exit.  An IOException if the channel was closed for example.

Comment: Code is working properly (updating db etc.). I have disabled other threads and pool.submit statement in above code. Still javaw.exe uses [13 % on my laptop (64 bit)  300K memory] and [50 % on other laptop(32bit) 50K memory]

Comment: non-blocking mode and NO selector is just plain dumb, take notes! 50% cpu utilization also means you have dual-core CPU and I guess you run the code on windows too.

Comment: Yes its dual core & windows. Will learn about selectors. Which is better ?
non-blocking+selector  OR  blocking+no selector.
  I Use same channel for sending/receiving to different IP/Ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html):

> If a datagram is immediately available, or if this channel is in blocking mode and one eventually becomes available, then the datagram is copied into the given byte buffer and its source address is returned. If this channel is in non-blocking mode and a datagram is not immediately available then this method immediately returns null.

Maybe your call to channel.receive(recvbuf) does not block, so you are looping at inifite speed which explains your CPU load.

Comment: I use these for Channel-> channel=DatagramChannel.open();
  channel.socket().bind(null);channel.configureBlocking(false);

Comment: Check if `receivedSocketAddress = channel.receive(recvbuf);` is of value **null**.

Comment: And in _check_ I mean like in _debug_ ;)

Comment: by changing to channel.configureBlocking(true);  cpu usage is fine 1-2% but will i miss any packets ?.  Packets can come at any random time in any amount.

Comment: you won't miss any packets since 'channel.receive(recvbuf)' will block until a packet is available.